# How do I set the precision of a floating variable in C++?

Tags: c++, precision

I have already tried the `setprecision()` method, but the IDE is displaying a "not declared in scope" error .

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/ Have you included `<iomanip>` ?

Comment: A floating point *variable* has exactly the precision that it's type gives it. The *formatted text* that *results* from `<<`ing that variable is controlled by objects in `<iomanip>`

Answer (score 1):

In order to allow for std::precision() you should look at the example below:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main() { 
    std::cout << std::setprecision(5) << 3.44444444444 << std::endl;
}
```